# NAudio not playing, but WaveProvider32 Read is being called

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, naudio

I'm trying to combine NAudio with Reactive Extentions, and I'm having an issue getting NAudio to play the audio.

The following is my code so far:

```
 public class WaveOutPlayer : IDisposable
{
    WaveOut wavOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());

    public WaveOutPlayer(int device, int sampleRate, int channels, IStereoSource source)
    {
        var provider = new WavProv(source, sampleRate, channels);
        provider.SetWaveFormat(sampleRate,channels);

        wavOut.Init(provider);
    }

    private class WavProv : WaveProvider32
    {
        AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        ConcurrentQueue<float> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<float>();

        public WavProv(IStereoSource source, int sampleRate, int channels)
        {
            source.ChannelLeft
           .Zip(source.ChannelRight, (ls, rs) => new double[] { ls, rs })      //one sample from each channel
           .SelectMany(samps => samps)                                         //convert to samples array l,r,l,r,l
           .Buffer(sampleRate * channels * 1)                                     //buffer samplerate*channels*2 seconds
           .Select(x => x.ToArray())                                            // to observable of chunks
           .Do(x => { are.Set(); })
           .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
           .Subscribe(data =>
           {
               //queue.Enqueue((float)data);
               data.ToList().ForEach((x) => queue.Enqueue((float)x));
           });

        }

        public override int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int sampleCount) 
        {
            int itemsRead;

            if (!queue.Any())                                                    //No data in the queue
            {
                //are.WaitOne();
                buffer = Enumerable.Repeat(0.0f, sampleCount).ToArray();        //Wait for some data
                itemsRead = sampleCount;
            }
            else
            {

                //number of items to read is lower of  samplecount or items in queue
                int itemsToRead = (queue.Count() > sampleCount) ? sampleCount : queue.Count();

                for (itemsRead = 0; itemsRead < itemsToRead; itemsRead++)
                {
                    float res;
                    if(queue.TryDequeue(out res))
                        buffer[itemsRead + offset] = res;       //add items from queue to buffer
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Requested:{0}, Read: {1}",sampleCount, itemsRead);
            return itemsRead;
        }
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        wavOut.Play();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        wavOut.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The Read method is being called, and the Console.WriteLine is showing I'm always providing enough data. Incidently, If I slow down the production of signal, such that I need to occasionally provide an all zeros buffer, (code not present currently) then I get a 'clicking' sound.

Is there any other issues/gotchas that I've missed?

e.g. Is the amplitude range between 0-1 only, or does it support the full range of float?

Thanks

Comment: GregC, agreed the code did have issues, however I was more interested in getting any sound at the time, rather than getting a clean sound! Please see updated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much more advisable to use NAudio's `BufferedWaveProvider` instead of the whole reset event / queue. It was designed for scenarios like these.

You will encounter breaks when the player's buffer runs out abruptly - the data is not streamed fast enough.

Secondly, let me clear up the function signature:

`int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int sampleCount)`

You will be supplied with a buffer, an offset in the buffer, and a chunk size. The value you returned indicates the number of items you could supply for this Read operation.
You are **not required** to supply an exact number of bytes as corresponds to the samples requested.

So if you wanted to supply silence, don't construct and return a buffer of zeros, and instead simply return 0 as the read length.

Finally, if you don't want an abrupt cut off, you can slowly decrease the amplitude of the last set of samples - it can be as simple as multiplying by `(N - n) / N` (n ϵ [0, N]). Cut off due to a buffer underrun is an entirely different issue.

**N.B.**

Let me add that your present solution is a not a good way to do this in production. Using a lot of objects in between will eventually lead to a lot of latency issues when garbage collection comes knocking. Mark Heath, the author of NAudio, has used a lot of tricks to minimize Garbage collection, like reusing buffers, EventArgs and the like, so it would be unjust if it went to waste.

Comment: I dont know much about nAudio, but I agree with Asti's comments and would like to add that using AutoResetEvents (or any WaitHandle) with Rx is a code smell.

Comment: @asti, 1) Thanks, I wasn't aware of BufferedWaveProvider. 2) I understood that returning 0 from Read, is the same as saying 'end of stream'. Regarding your N.B, I agree, and this isn't for production quality code, Its for a simple and easy to read Signal Processing pipeline that students can play with.

Comment: @LeeCampbell Agreed, and the current version of the code doesn't use any syncronization, I added these to rule out a threading issue as a cause at the time.